# Unpivot table in Databricks/Spark SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark-sql

I'm having problems migrating a script in Oracle SQL to Spark SQL or SQL Server, I need to run this script in an instance of Databricks, but in SQL Server/Spark SQL, I can't find the unpivot function, I tried to rewrite this table using another way, however ops data is coming different, can you help me with what I'm doing wrong?

**SQL with Unpivot**

```
select count(*) from
  (WITH 
    pq AS (
        SELECT 
            DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
            DT_OUTBOUND_DATE,
            DT_INBOUND_DATE,
            upper(least(substr(TX_TRECHO,0,3) || substr(TX_TRECHO,5,3) ,substr(TX_TRECHO,5,3) || substr(TX_TRECHO,0,3))) as TX_MERCADO,
            SUM(NB_QUANTIDADE_PESQUISA) AS NB_QUANTIDADE_PESQUISA
        FROM 
            bigq.bigq_data_pesquisas
        WHERE 
            (date_format(DT_CAPTURE_DATE, 'yMMdd') >= '20210816'
            AND date_format(DT_CAPTURE_DATE, 'yMMdd') <= '20210816')
            AND DT_OUTBOUND_DATE >= DT_CAPTURE_DATE
            AND (DT_INBOUND_DATE >= DT_OUTBOUND_DATE OR DT_INBOUND_DATE IS NULL)
        GROUP BY
            DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
            DT_OUTBOUND_DATE,
            DT_INBOUND_DATE,
            upper(least(substr(TX_TRECHO,0,3) || substr(TX_TRECHO,5,3) ,substr(TX_TRECHO,5,3) || substr(TX_TRECHO,0,3)))
    ),
    pn AS (
        SELECT 
            DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
            DT_OUTBOUND_DATE,
            DT_INBOUND_DATE,
            upper(least(substr(TX_TRECHO,0,3) || substr(TX_TRECHO,5,3) ,substr(TX_TRECHO,5,3) || substr(TX_TRECHO,0,3))) as TX_MERCADO,
            SUM(NB_QUANTIDADE_PNRS) AS NB_QUANTIDADE_PNRS
        FROM 
            bigq.bigq_data_pnrs
        WHERE 
            (date_format(DT_CAPTURE_DATE, 'yMMdd') >= '20210816'
            AND date_format(DT_CAPTURE_DATE, 'yMMdd') <=  '20210816')
            AND DT_OUTBOUND_DATE >= DT_CAPTURE_DATE
            AND (DT_INBOUND_DATE >= DT_OUTBOUND_DATE OR DT_INBOUND_DATE IS NULL)
        GROUP BY
            DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
            DT_OUTBOUND_DATE,
            DT_INBOUND_DATE,
            upper(least(substr(TX_TRECHO,0,3) || substr(TX_TRECHO,5,3) ,substr(TX_TRECHO,5,3) || substr(TX_TRECHO,0,3)))
    )
    SELECT
        DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
        DT_FLIGHT_DATE,
        TX_FLIGHT_TYPE,
        TX_MERCADO,
        SUM(NVL(NB_PESQUISA, 0)),
        SUM(NVL(NB_PNRS, 0))
    FROM (
        SELECT
            pq.DT_CAPTURE_DATE             DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
            pq.DT_OUTBOUND_DATE            DT_OUTBOUND_DATE,
            pq.DT_INBOUND_DATE             DT_INBOUND_DATE,
            pq.TX_MERCADO                  TX_MERCADO,
            SUM(pq.NB_QUANTIDADE_PESQUISA) NB_PESQUISA,
            SUM(pn.NB_QUANTIDADE_PNRS)     NB_PNRS
        FROM pq
        LEFT JOIN pn 
        ON 
            pq.DT_CAPTURE_DATE = pn.DT_CAPTURE_DATE
            AND pq.TX_MERCADO = pn.TX_MERCADO
            AND pq.DT_OUTBOUND_DATE = pn.DT_OUTBOUND_DATE
            AND pq.DT_INBOUND_DATE = pn.DT_INBOUND_DATE
        GROUP BY
            pq.DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
            pq.DT_OUTBOUND_DATE,
            pq.DT_INBOUND_DATE,
            pq.TX_MERCADO
        
        UNION
        
        SELECT
            pn.DT_CAPTURE_DATE               DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
            pn.DT_OUTBOUND_DATE              DT_OUTBOUND_DATE,
            pn.DT_INBOUND_DATE               DT_INBOUND_DATE,
            pn.TX_MERCADO                    TX_MERCADO,
            SUM(pq.NB_QUANTIDADE_PESQUISA)   NB_PESQUISA,
            SUM(pn.NB_QUANTIDADE_PNRS)       NB_PNRS
        FROM pq
        RIGHT JOIN pn 
        ON 
            pq.DT_CAPTURE_DATE = pn.DT_CAPTURE_DATE
            AND pq.TX_MERCADO = pn.TX_MERCADO
            AND pq.DT_OUTBOUND_DATE = pn.DT_OUTBOUND_DATE
            AND pq.DT_INBOUND_DATE = pn.DT_INBOUND_DATE
        GROUP BY
            pn.DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
            pn.DT_OUTBOUND_DATE,
            pn.DT_INBOUND_DATE,
            pn.TX_MERCADO
    )
    UNPIVOT(
        (DT_FLIGHT_DATE)
        FOR TX_FLIGHT_TYPE
        IN (
            (DT_OUTBOUND_DATE) AS 'Outbound', 
            (DT_INBOUND_DATE) AS 'Inbound'
        )
    )
    GROUP BY 
        DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
        DT_FLIGHT_DATE,
        TX_FLIGHT_TYPE,
        TX_MERCADO
   )
```

**This is my script:**

```
select count(*) from
  (WITH pq
     AS (SELECT DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
                DT_OUTBOUND_DATE,
                DT_INBOUND_DATE,
                Upper(Least(Substr(TX_TRECHO, 0, 3) || Substr(TX_TRECHO, 5, 3), Substr(TX_TRECHO, 5, 3) || Substr(TX_TRECHO, 0, 3)))
                AS
                  TX_MERCADO,
                  SUM(NB_QUANTIDADE_PESQUISA)
                AS
                  NB_QUANTIDADE_PESQUISA
         FROM   bigq.bigq_data_pesquisas
         WHERE  (date_format(DT_CAPTURE_DATE, 'yMMdd') >= '20210816'
                   AND date_format(DT_CAPTURE_DATE, 'yMMdd') <= '20210816')
                 AND DT_OUTBOUND_DATE >= DT_CAPTURE_DATE
                 AND (DT_INBOUND_DATE >= DT_OUTBOUND_DATE
                      OR DT_INBOUND_DATE IS NULL)
         GROUP BY DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
                  DT_OUTBOUND_DATE,
                  DT_INBOUND_DATE,
                  Upper(Least(Substr(TX_TRECHO, 0, 3) || Substr(TX_TRECHO, 5, 3), Substr(TX_TRECHO, 5, 3) || Substr(TX_TRECHO, 0, 3)))),
     pn
     AS (SELECT DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
                DT_OUTBOUND_DATE,
                DT_INBOUND_DATE,
                Upper(Least(Substr(TX_TRECHO, 0, 3) || Substr(TX_TRECHO, 5, 3), Substr(TX_TRECHO, 5, 3) || Substr(TX_TRECHO, 0, 3)))
                AS
                  TX_MERCADO,
                  Sum(NB_QUANTIDADE_PNRS)
                AS
                  NB_QUANTIDADE_PNRS
         FROM   bigq.bigq_data_pnrs
         WHERE  (date_format(DT_CAPTURE_DATE, 'yMMdd') >= '20210816'
                   AND date_format(DT_CAPTURE_DATE, 'yMMdd') <= '20210816')
                AND DT_OUTBOUND_DATE >= DT_CAPTURE_DATE
                AND (DT_INBOUND_DATE >= DT_OUTBOUND_DATE
                      OR DT_INBOUND_DATE IS NULL)
         GROUP  BY DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
                   DT_OUTBOUND_DATE,
                   DT_INBOUND_DATE,
                   Upper(Least(Substr(TX_TRECHO, 0, 3) || Substr(TX_TRECHO, 5, 3), Substr(TX_TRECHO, 5, 3) || Substr(TX_TRECHO, 0, 3)))),
     seu_bloco
     AS (SELECT pq.DT_CAPTURE_DATE      DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
                pq.DT_OUTBOUND_DATE      DT_OUTBOUND_DATE,
                pq.DT_INBOUND_DATE      DT_INBOUND_DATE,
                pq.TX_MERCADO           TX_MERCADO,
                Sum(pq.NB_QUANTIDADE_PESQUISA) NB_PESQUISA,
                Sum(pn.NB_QUANTIDADE_PNRS) NB_PNRS
         FROM   pq
                LEFT JOIN pn
                       ON pq.DT_CAPTURE_DATE = pn.DT_CAPTURE_DATE
                          AND pq.TX_MERCADO = pn.TX_MERCADO
                          AND pq.DT_OUTBOUND_DATE = pn.DT_OUTBOUND_DATE
                          AND pq.DT_INBOUND_DATE = pn.DT_INBOUND_DATE
         GROUP  BY pq.DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
                   pq.DT_OUTBOUND_DATE,
                   pq.DT_INBOUND_DATE,
                   pq.TX_MERCADO
         UNION
         SELECT pn.DT_CAPTURE_DATE      DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
                pn.DT_OUTBOUND_DATE      DT_OUTBOUND_DATE,
                pn.DT_INBOUND_DATE      DT_INBOUND_DATE,
                pn.TX_MERCADO           TX_MERCADO,
                Sum(pq.NB_QUANTIDADE_PESQUISA) NB_PESQUISA,
                Sum(pn.NB_QUANTIDADE_PNRS) NB_PNRS
         FROM   pq
                RIGHT JOIN pn
                        ON pq.DT_CAPTURE_DATE = pn.DT_CAPTURE_DATE
                           AND pq.TX_MERCADO = pn.TX_MERCADO
                           AND pq.DT_OUTBOUND_DATE = pn.DT_OUTBOUND_DATE
                           AND pq.DT_INBOUND_DATE = pn.DT_INBOUND_DATE
         GROUP  BY pn.DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
                   pn.DT_OUTBOUND_DATE,
                   pn.DT_INBOUND_DATE,
                   pn.TX_MERCADO) 
SELECT DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
      DT_OUTBOUND_DATE DT_FLIGHT_DATE,
      'Outbound'   TX_FLIGHT_TYPE,
       TX_MERCADO,
       Sum(NB_PESQUISA) NB_PESQUISA,
       Sum(NB_PNRS) NB_PNRS
FROM   seu_bloco
GROUP  BY DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
         DT_OUTBOUND_DATE,
         'Outbound',
          TX_MERCADO
UNION ALL
SELECT DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
       DT_INBOUND_DATE,
       'Inbound',
       TX_MERCADO,
       Sum(NB_PESQUISA),
       Sum(NB_PNRS)
FROM   seu_bloco
GROUP  BY DT_CAPTURE_DATE,
          DT_INBOUND_DATE,
          'Inbound',
          TX_MERCADO)
```

Comment: Apparently the Spark SQL equivalent to `UNPIVOT` is `STACK` https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/how-to-pivot-table-and-unpivot-a-spark-dataframe/

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your help, I managed to solve, as I understand it, the Unpivot function, disregards empty lines, so the values ​​are different, there really is nothing wrong with my script, but that it is reading the empty lines... so I needed to add a clause is not null for both scripts to match :D

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve, as i understand it, the Unpivot function, disregards empty lines, so the values ​​are different, there really is nothing wrong with my script, but that it is reading the empty lines... so I needed to add a clause is not null for both scripts to match